# How to load only base type in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

Consider following case:

I have base class inherited by another two.
For instance we will have:

```
class Base
{

}
class DerivedA : Base
{

}
class DerivedB : Base
{

}
```

When I request base entity with code like

context.Base.Where(q => q.Id == id).First();

Entity Framework generate a full set of joins to every derived entity which results in below acceptable perfomance of query.
What **I want is to load only base entity** without joining it to derived ones.

The only solution I found described here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/09/17/tip-35-how-to-write-oftypeonly-tentity.aspx.
But that did not work for me. EF still generates huge query.

Writing queries like:

```
context.Base.Where(q => !(q is DerivedA) && !(q is DerivedB)).First();
```

**doesn't suits me** either due to constantly increasing amount of derived types.

Are there any possible solutions apart from those I mentioned?

Comment: What do you determine to be "below acceptable performance"? And I'm curious why would you want a base class?

Comment: "*What I want is to load only base entity without joining it to derived ones*": Does that mean that you only want the base *part* of the entities or that you only want entities that *are* of the base type? For the latter keep in mind that the queries need joins into the tables of the derived types to determine if the entity is of base type (basically if the result of the joins is empty, the entity is of base type, otherwise it isn't). So, you can't avoid the joins in that case (that's the price of TPT inheritance). If you want only the base *part* a projection is probably the correct way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using Table-per-type => EF must generate those joins because it doesn't know what type your entity really is. If your record from `Base` has a related record in `DerivedA` table **IT MUST NOT** create instance of `Base` entity for that record - **IT MUST** create instance of `DerivedA` and it needs to make joins to get this knowledge.

It is for a long discussion why this is not allowed but simply entity is from object world - it is atomic data structure which can be saved to multiple tables but that is invisible to object world. If you persist a `Base` you will load back a `Base` but if you persist `DerivedA` you will always load back `DerivedA` and never just `Base` because it would break the atomicity of the entity.

I didn't try it but I assume that ESQL `OFTYPE ONLY` operator should do joins as well to make sure that it really loads real instances of the base entity instead of corrupted instances of derived entities.

Table-per-type produces slow queries. .NET 4.5 should improve it but I think improvements will not target these cases - I think they will target `OfType` for derived types and projections.

If you want only data from `Base` table your best options are:

- Hand written SQL - projections in [.NET 4.0 still do some unnecessary](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/08/17/performance-considerations-when-using-tpt-table-per-type-inheritance-in-the-entity-framework.aspx) joins or unions
- .NET 4.5 and projection in Linq

Comment: Where would us EF newbies be, if you weren't around? lol Is there a particular way/proper practice to use inheritance and when not to?

Comment: I learned about performance of TPT queries probably the same way as you - we had nice object model with big TPT inheritance structure and our performance on real data was terrible - we ended with creating special database views for information we needed (and joins which very necessary) and mapped them as separate readonly entities.

Comment: @Ladislav, can we create a separate (but similar) entity to the parent, and map it to the same table?

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce an abstract intermediary class with no further meaning/function from which all derived types have to derive:

```
class Base
{

}
abstract class DerivedBase : Base
{

}
class DerivedA : DerivedBase 
{

}
class DerivedB : DerivedBase 
{

}
```

Then you can do a simple query no mather how many derived classes exist:

```
context.Bases
  .Where(b => !(b is DerivedBase))
  ...
```

Comment: This could work, but note that in TPT mapping, this will add another table that will become part of the query join clause in every query for objects inheriting `DerivedBase`, which in this case would be all of them.

Comment: Thanx @MarcL. -  since I only use TPH I did not think about that.